# Comparing integers from tuples in for loop

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare int values from a list of tuples while iterate over the list. Concretely i have a list of tuples like so:

`numbers_tokenized = [('2900', 368),('7,', 378),('2900', 379),('33', 384),('34', 385),('40', 386),('00', 387),('33', 389),('34', 390),('40', 391),('01', 392),('7', 410),('2900', 412),('7', 422),('191', 424),('2900', 425),('33', 428),('34', 429),('40', 430),('00', 431),('33', 433),('34', 434),('40', 435),('01', 436)]`

What i wanna do is check if the second element in a tuple is the element of the tuple next in the list + 1. For instance `384,385,386,387` from the list above.

I have the following loop that i think should do the job.

```
cons_nums = list()
for x in range(1,len(numbers_tokenized)):
    if numbers_tokenized[x][1]-1 == numbers_tokenized[x-1][1]:
        cons_nums.append(numbers_tokenized[x-1])
    else:
        continue
```

However this gives me the following output, which does not make much sense to me.

```
cons_nums = [('7,', 329),
 ('7,', 338),
 ('7,', 349),
 ('7,', 367),
 ('7,', 378),
 ('33', 384),
 ('34', 385),
 ('40', 386),
 ('33', 389),
 ('34', 390),
 ('40', 391),
 ('191', 424),
 ('33', 428),
 ('34', 429),
 ('40', 430),
 ('33', 433),
 ('34', 434),
 ('40', 435)]
```

Am i making some obvious mistake or why is this not working?

EDIT:

In a successful loop `cons_nums` would look like this:

```
cons_nums = [('7,', 378),('2900', 379),('33', 384),('34', 385),('40', 386),('00', 387),('33', 389),('34', 390),('40', 391),('01', 392),('191', 424),('2900', 425),('33', 428),('34', 429),('40', 430),('00', 431),('33', 433),('34', 434),('40', 435),('01', 436)]
```

Comment: if the second element in a tuple is the element of the tuple next <- first or second element of the next one?

Comment: Could you provide what you expect `cons_nums` to look like if this loop was successful?

Comment: whats the expected output? also whats wrong with `378,379`

Comment: It actually seems to be working exactly as intended for me. I'm not sure where you think its failing

Comment: I added a piece of code to reflect what cons_nums is supposed to contain after the loop.

Comment: your output is missing `('7,', 378),('2900', 379)` unless I misunderstand

Comment: woops yes sorry, i'll fix that @eagle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just if's and loops:

```
numbers_tokenized = [('2900', 368),('7,', 378),('2900', 379),('33', 384),('34', 385),('40', 386),('00', 387),('33', 389),('34', 390),('40', 391),('01', 392),('7', 410),('2900', 412),('7', 422),('191', 424),('2900', 425),('33', 428),('34', 429),('40', 430),('00', 431),('33', 433),('34', 434),('40', 435),('01', 436)]

cons_nums = list()
for x in range(0,len(numbers_tokenized)-1):
    if numbers_tokenized[x][1]+1 == numbers_tokenized[x+1][1]:
      if numbers_tokenized[x] not in cons_nums:
        cons_nums.append(numbers_tokenized[x])
      if numbers_tokenized[x+1] not in cons_nums:
        cons_nums.append(numbers_tokenized[x+1])


print(cons_nums)
```

Output:

```
[('7,', 378), ('2900', 379), ('33', 384), ('34', 385), ('40', 386), ('00', 387), ('33', 389), ('34', 390), ('40', 391), ('01', 392), ('191', 424), ('2900', 425), ('33', 428), ('34', 429), ('40', 430), ('00', 431), ('33', 433), ('34', 434), ('40', 435), ('01', 436)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
shifted=zip(numbers_tokenized[1:],numbers_tokenized[:-1])
output=[i[1] for i,j in shifted if i[1]-1==j[1]]
```

Edit:
This does it, but to remove the duplicates I've used set that doesn't maintain the order, if you want the same order you can simply use a loop or similar list comprehension.

```
shifted=zip(numbers_tokenized[:-1],numbers_tokenized[1:])
output=[j for i in shifted if i[0][1]+1==i[1][1] for j in i]
output=list(set(output))
```

Comment: No sorry. That is very close to the wrong output i posted in the question.